# Latex commands request feature

Tags: feature-request

Poker is a game that needs a heavy use of probability theory and statistics. Then will be usefull to use the latex commands. Is this possible to have this feature available on this site?

Comment: Do you have some questions that would specifically use this? If so, that would be great :)

Comment: At this moment no, but I think this feature will be usefull.

Comment: @TobyBooth I cannot back this question enough, in order to have any decent discussion on poker these days you need to use a lot of maths and the only way that is possible on a forum is if it has Latex capabilities, check out maths stack exchange to see how it works (I think they use mathjax). A question that would need latex for an answer would be the question that I posted on derivation of the Chen formula

Comment: I don't know if it's helpful now (this question seems kinda dead), but I believe the question which [hmmmm](http://meta.poker.stackexchange.com/users/354/hmmmm) was referencing as an example is [this one](http://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/1160/mathematical-derivation-of-the-chen-formula). For what it's worth, I echo [hmmmm](http://meta.poker.stackexchange.com/users/354/hmmmm)'s comment and think this would be very useful for the wide variety of statistical and mathematical questions which appear on this site.

Answer (score 3):

I am not completely convinced that this is necessary, but I do completely agree with the arguments in favor of it. I think the key point comes down to the fact that by providing tools to encourage detailed mathematical questions, we will ultimately be encouraging more high-level theoretical discussions, and those are the issues that the true poker savants will find interesting. We need more questions like that to interest the types of players who will make the site thrive. So it is worth it to add such a feature, even if most of our current users would never use it.

Listen to the StackOverflow podcast #87 for more on this. Joel Spolsky (Founder of StackExchange) describes why a law site would need questions that only interest professional lawyers and judges. This is a good parallel to this issue in our community.

Answer (score 1):

Given hand probability is based on frequecy Latex or MathJax could be very powerful

From example this is a question I asked on [stats.stackexchange.com](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/193267/ways-to-make-a-straight-in-poker)

You get people that want to ask about outs based computations
Need a way to discuss how frequency is done

This question [What are the odds of a at least a certain amount of aces being dealt depending on the number of players?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/6646/what-are-the-odds-of-a-at-least-a-certain-amount-of-aces-being-dealt-depending-o) would benifit from MathJax

This [question](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/5505/probability-of-flopping-straight-flush?rq=1) would also benefit